# My alterate flashing LED program is not working

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, assembly

I am trying to program my Arduino UNO ATMega 328p in assembler to implement a ﬂashing pattern with two LEDs. When one LED is oﬀ, the other must be on. I have made a program but it is showing errors and I don't know how to fix it. I have done it Atmel Studio 7. Please help if you can.

Here is my program:

```
main:

sbi 0x04, 5
sbi 0x04, 4

start:

sbi 0x05, 5
ldi r16,1000
rcall delay
cbi 0x05, 5

sbi 0x05, 4
ldi r16,1000
rcall delay
cbi 0x05, 4

rjmp start

delay:

dec r8
brne delay
dec r9
brne delay
dec r16
brne delay
ret
```

Comment: Please show the errors you received.

Comment: When I run this I get 2 errors: Operand(s) out of range in 'ldi r16,0x3e8' Operand(s) out of range in 'ldi r16,0x3e8'

Comment: I think I found the problem now, thanks anyways :)

Comment: @user58745 Then please write an answer to your question, so that others can learn from this.